# Usage of なら in this context 俺相手なら なんでもいい みたいだった

Tags: grammar, translation, conditionals

俺相手なら なんでもいい みたいだった

I am still learning Japanese so if my  translation/understanding of this sentence is wrong please let me know, but I have translated part of this sentence to mean "seemed like anything is fine"  And I know that this kanji 俺 translates to I;me and this kanji 相手 translates to counterpart. But I need some help understanding the ならpart of the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「俺相手{おれあいて}なら なんでもいい みたいだった」

Without more context, it would be impossible to translate this sentence perfectly because Japanese is an extremely contextual language.

「なら」 is a conditional conjunction -- "***if***", "***as long as***", etc.

So, all I could come up with would be something like:

> "It seemed anything would do as long as it were done/performed against/toward/with me."